# Intellij - Disable "whole project searching"

Tags: search, ide

When I want to find usage of accessors in my Java class IntelliJ perform searching in whole project which hangs whole IDE. Can I disable or narrow this "deep" searching?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the latest version of IDEA Ultimate--(2017.3)
In the menu for accessor usage, there should be a filter icon that you can use to narrow the search to a group as you define it. See the below link for more info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-usages-in-project.html

hope this helps!